# Not loading CSS with safari browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

i made a simple HTML index page, my CSS is working for the main part.
But i made the footer part, HTML is showing but my CSS doesn't load at all on safari. When i check the inspector i don't see any CSS loading.
And this issue only for safari .
So i would like to know where is my problem and why this is happening? If someone could help me solve this problem. 
I'm getting NUTS about it !

I have tried to include the HTML and CSS in same document (no style.css file) and it is correctly displaying.

Please check [this link](https://shopping.geocities.jp/ihr/) (open it with safari): the footer part.
other browser works fine.

Comment: Please create a minimal, working example for us so that we can reproduce the problem. Don't link to external sites, put the relevant code here.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: @cloned The thing is that i don't know what part of my code is wrong or incorrect.

Comment: sounds like a css property that isn't compatible with Safari

Answer (score 0):

It's a CSS issue.
Hints : look at your body element.
Use your console, add a position relative, a min-height of 100% and continue to debug ;)

As it's not a minimal reproductible exemple please continue a bit by yourself and hit us back when you're stuck.

Comment: Sorry, i do not really understand about your hint. I have tried what you said and playing inside the code but still same issue.

Could you be more specific on where could be my mistake. I really don't get it.
That will be really helpful ! 

Thanks boss !

Comment: Hi, I just opened Safari and tried to put a min-height 100% on `body` element, position relative and started to see things happen. 
I'll let you search a bit more this way